# Find $xyz$ if $x^2+2y^2+2z^2-2x-6y-10z+2xy+2yz+14=0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

The question is

> Find the sum of all possible values of $xyz$ given that $x, y, z\in \Bbb Z$ satisfying 
>   $$x^2+2y^2+2z^2-2x-6y-10z+2xy+2yz+14=0.$$

*Some thought so far:*

Obviously $x$ is even. I assume $x=2k$, but I don't know how to proceed. I tried to complete squares and it became more complicated:
$$(x+y-1)^2+(y+z+4)^2+(z-9)^2=82.$$

WolframAlpha gives $48$ set of solutions, so I think there are ways calculating **sum of  all possible values** of $xyz$ without finding  all solutions.

Comment: $48$ is exactly the number of ways to write $82$ as the sum of three integer squares...

Comment: Sorry, but $$(x+y-1)^2+(y+z+4)^2+(z-9)^2=82$$ is not derived from the above. Checking the constant terms, $1^2+4^2+9^2-82\neq14$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Completing the squares:
$$(x+y-1)^2+(y+z-2)^2+(z-3)^2=0 \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}x+y-1=0\\ y+z-2=0\\ z-3=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
(x,y,z)=(2,-1,3) \Rightarrow xyz=-6.$$

Comment: Elegant way to solve such a problem !!

Answer (score 0):

Completing the squares was great idea! Now write $82$ as the sum of three integer squares. There aren't many ways to do that. Each way gives you a linear system for $x,y,z$, which may or may not have integer solutions.

Comment: On the other hand, there may be a solution that finds $xyz$ without finding $x,y,z$ separately.